# sitecore, installing a package and publishing standard values / template changes

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am trying to publish some template changes with standard value as part of a package in a different environment.  Once installed and published the changes are not showing up.  I've reset IIS and manually cleared cache to be sure as well.  I basically have to manually add a new field to the template and then apply standard values to it in order for it to show up.  Is there a restriction on how to install / publish such changes?  Perhaps i need to follow some order such as installing the template, then applying the standard values?  Anyway, I realize that there is not a ton of information and that perhaps our sitecore implementation is the problem, but I've been banging my head against it for long enough that it is worth a shot here.

Thanks,  Rob

Comment: After installing a package ona target environment, what kind of publishing do you use? Incremental or smart? Or even full?

Comment: heck, I tried all of them this time around.  I usually use smart and include all sub items.

Comment: Then it's not what I thought it could be - hoped this would be a quick one :)

Comment: Can you check the Web database to see if the changes are there or not after a publish?

Comment: yeah, i check the web database.  I can see the changes in the  content editor on both web/master.  everything acts like a caching problem, but I can assure you it is not that.

Answer (score 1):

Does your package include the template itself, in addition to the new fields and standard values? If you've recently added the __Standard values item, the template itself would have been updated as well with the reference to its standard values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the answer to techphoria's question is YES.  Here's the next step:

Are you sure you're editing the same templates?  That is, have you checked that the Sitecore ID of these items are the same?  And the __Standard Values item ID is also identical in both environments?  In the past, I have inadvertently created two __Standard Values items on a single template by using the package installer.

Further question: did you change any fields shared/versioned flag?  If so, there is a known issue with using packages to move those template changes.  In short, it won't work... I believe this bug was fixed, but definitely present in 6.2, possibly 6.3.1 even.

More questions... what do you mean by "apply standard values to it"?  It sounds like the templates you are updating should already have a __Standard Values item?  So exactly what changes are not showing up?  You are not seeing the new fields at all?  You are not seeing the new fields in standard values?  Or you are not seeing the new standard values in items that use the template?  Are you SURE that the target item in question hasn't previously had a value saved in the field?  Once that happens, it won't get standard values unless you manually reset it... even if you blank out the value.

Comment: I didn't change any shared or version fields.  by apply standard values, basically i was just adding a new lookup / drop down type field that needed to have  default.  I could see the value populated in each individual item in the content editor, but the value wasn't coming across in my code behind queries, such as items[0].Fields["blah"  etc.

Comment: What about when you preview?  This sounds like a publishing issue now, if you can see the correct values in Content Editor.  Theoretically, Content Editor is using the same API you are.